# Run server project in debug mode while testing client project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

Let's say I have Client and Server projects in one solution. I wrote Unit Test project to test Client but to execute tests I need to run Server in debug mode from Unit Test project. How to do that?

Comment: If you need to run a server to 'unit test' the client code then its not a unit test, its an integration test - a unit test would mock/stub out the server interface and test the client code does what is expected of it.  You would then have unit tests for the server.

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests usually test just one component (be that a class or a method) at one time. Seems like you are trying to do integration testing. In my opinion you should abstract the server away from the client so that you can focus on the client only. Or vice versa. With the direction you are currently going you'll probably end up with way too complicated tests that will fail for server **and** client errors.

If you do want to do the integration test then you could just spin up a server in a separate AppDomain and interact with it from your unit test code as you usually do. But like I said these kinds of tests are usually too complicated to be of any use and are very hard to maintain.

But you should provide more details on both the client and the server to get better answers. How do they interact, what are their roles?